# How to get next element in Immutable List when use .map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

i have 1 immutable List like this

```
const list = new List([
new Map({ title: 'first', complete: true }),
new Map({ title: 'second',complete: false }),
])
```

when i use

```
list.map((value,index) => {
//HOW TO GET VALUE OF NEXT ELEMENT IN HERE ?
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
list.map((value,index) => {
  const next = list.get(index + 1);
  // next will be undefined when the value is last one in the list (and index + 1) is out of bounds because of that
})
```

Just for clarification this example is using the fact that Immutable List is descendant of Collection.Indexed which has [get(index) method](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection.Indexed/get)